# Formatting numbers using Excel syntax in Scala or Java

Tags: java, excel, scala, apache-poi, number-formatting

Does anyone know of a JVM-based formatting library that can handle Excel-style number formats?

Apache POI has [`DataFormatter`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) but its API is geared towards manipulating Excel documents. My use case is simply formatting numbers using an Excel format specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Apache POI's DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) in a stand-alone mode if you'd like

The method you want is [formatRawCellContents](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatRawCellContents%28double,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29)

Assuming you know the format string, and don't require any of the special formatting / localisation that can happen with the first few builtin formats, you can pass `-1` for the format index. Then you'd just do something like

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

...

String formatted = formatter.formatRawCellContents(1.234, -1, "#,###.00");
```

And you'll get your double value formatted based on the given Excel-style format

Comment: Thanks, I missed that method when I scanned the API.